# Definition of Connect, Processing, Waiting in apache bench

Tags: performance, apache, benchmarking

When I run apache bench I get results like:

```
Command: abs.exe -v 3 -n 10 -c 1 https://mysite
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      203  213   8.1    219     219
Processing:    78  177  88.1    172     359
Waiting:       78  169  84.6    156     344
Total:        281  389  86.7    391     564
```

I can't seem to find the definition of Connect, Processing and Waiting.  What do those numbers mean?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From http://chestofbooks.com/computers/webservers/apache/Stas-Bekman/Practical-mod_perl/9-1-1-ApacheBench.html:

> **Connect and Waiting times**
>
> The amount of time it took to establish the connection and get the first bits of a response
>
> **Processing time**
>
> The server response time—i.e., the time it took for the server to process the request and send a reply
>
> **Total time**
>
> The sum of the Connect and Processing times

I equate this to:

- Connect time: the amount of time it took for the socket to open
- Processing time: first byte + transfer
- Waiting: time till first byte
- Total: Sum of Connect + Processing

Comment: I think processing time includes waiting time, otherwise total time would be connect + waiting + processing.

Answer (score 57):

By looking at the source code we find these timing points:

```
apr_time_t start,           /* Start of connection */
           connect,         /* Connected, start writing */
           endwrite,        /* Request written */
           beginread,       /* First byte of input */
           done;            /* Connection closed */
```

And when request is done some timings are stored as:

```
        s->starttime = c->start;
        s->ctime     = ap_max(0, c->connect - c->start);
        s->time      = ap_max(0, c->done - c->start);
        s->waittime  = ap_max(0, c->beginread - c->endwrite);
```

And the 'Processing time' is later calculated as

```
s->time - s->ctime;
```

So if we translate this to a timeline:

```
t1: Start of connection
t2: Connected, start writing
t3: Request written
t4: First byte of input
t5: Connection closed
```

Then the definitions would be:

```
Connect:      t1-t2   Most typically the network latency
Processing:   t2-t5   Time to receive full response after connection was opened
Waiting:      t3-t4   Time-to-first-byte after the request was sent
Total time:   t1-t5
```

Comment: Best answer on here. Thank you!

Comment: Where is apache bench source code hosted at? I can't seem to find it even in apache's open source listing.

Comment: Perfect! Thank You. Let me call you The Great Reverser!

Answer (score 2):

Connect: Time it takes to connect to remote host

Processing: Total time minus time it takes to connect to remote host

Waiting: Response first byte receive minus last byte sent

Total: From before connect till after the connection is closed